# Haskell where scope error

Tags: haskell

```
formatBill :: BillType -> String
formatBill bill = merge' [pname ++ dots ++ show pprice | (pname, pprice) <- bill]
    where
    dots = ['.' | x<-[1..(lineLength - length pname - length (show pprice))]]
```

This is my code - `formatBill` is a function that must return `String`.

An example of what it should return:

```
Product name.................. PRICE
Other product................. 4555
```

`merge'` is just `[String] -> String`

```
type BillType = [(String, Int)] -- BillType definition
lineLength = 30 -- length of row
```

These are the errors I get:

> code.hs:69:51: Not in scope: `pname'
>
> code.hs:69:72: Not in scope: `pprice'

Comment: Suggestion for readability: use `replicate k '.'` rather than `['.' | x <- [1..k]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `where` clause scopes over the whole function definition, so you can't use things that are only in scope in the list comprehension.

Either make `dots` into a function taking them as parameters:

```
formatBill :: BillType -> String
formatBill bill =
  merge' [pname ++ dots pname pprice ++ show pprice | (pname, pprice) <- bill]
    where
    dots pname pprice =
          ['.' | x<-[1..(lineLength - length pname - length (show pprice))]]
```

Or use a `let` inside the list comprehension:

```
formatBill :: BillType -> String
formatBill bill =
  merge' [pname ++ dots ++ show pprice
               | (pname, pprice) <- bill
               , let dots = ['.' | x <- [1..(lineLength
                                                - length pname
                                                - length (show pprice))]]]
```